# Backpropagation using Numpy Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, neural-network, backpropagation

i wanted to build a backpropagation for neural network only using numpy. the configuration is using a 3 input and aliasing with "inp" variable. using 4 neuron for hidden layer and put 2 neuron for the output. Nevertheless, i got an error while implement the backpropagation since the loop is showing about indexing error. Can you help me?

[Neural Network Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxXit.png)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Apr 19 02:28:04 2021

@author: hananta
"""

import numpy as np

inp = [1, 2, 0.5]       # input

weightIW = [[0.5, 0.4, 0.2, 0.3],
            [0.5, 0.3, 0.8, 0.7],
            [0.6, 0.2, 0.9, 0.8]]
weightLW = [[0.5, 0.3],
            [0.4, 0.5],
            [0.2, 0.6],
            [0.4, 0.7]]

biasIW = [0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2]
biasLW = [0.3, 0.4]

T = [0, 1]              # Target

def sigmoid(x):
   return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))  #Sigmoid Func

def deriv_sigmoid(x):
   return sigmoid(x) * (1-sigmoid(x))

print("Forward:")

Ziw = np.dot(inp, weightIW) + biasIW  # Matrix Multiplication
print("Input : ", inp)
print("Bobot / Ziw : ", Ziw)

Yiw = sigmoid(Ziw)
print("Prediksi / Yiw : ", Yiw)

Zlw = np.dot(Yiw, weightLW) + biasLW
print("Bobot / Zlw : ", Zlw)

Ylw = sigmoid(Zlw)
print("prediksi / Ylw : ", Ylw)

E = 1/2 * sum((T-Ylw) ** 2)     # MSE - Hasil dari Y dibandingkan dengan T
print("Error / E : ", E,'\n')


print("Backpropagation :")
alpha = 0.5
for c in range(2):
   for r in range(4):
      # turunan
      delta = -1 * (T[c] - Ylw[c]) * deriv_sigmoid(Ylw[c]) * Yiw[r]
      # update weight
     weightLW[r][c] = weightLW[r][c] - alpha * delta
print("WeightLW : ", weightLW)

alpha = 0.5
for c in range(2):
   delta = -1 * (T[c] - Ylw[c]) * deriv_sigmoid(Ylw[c])
   biasLW[c] = biasLW[c] - alpha * (-1 * (T[c] - Ylw[c]) * deriv_sigmoid(Ylw[c]))
print("biasLW : ", biasLW, '\n')

alpha = 0.5
for c in range(4):
   for r in range(3):
      # turunan
     delta = -1 * (Ylw[c] - Yiw[c]) * deriv_sigmoid(Yiw[c]) * inp[r]
      # update weight
      weightIW[r][c] = weightIW[r][c] - alpha * delta
print("WeightIW : ", weightIW)

alpha = 0.5
for c in range(4):
   delta = -1 * (Ylw[c] - Yiw[c]) * deriv_sigmoid(Yiw[c])
   biasIW[c] = biasIW[c] - alpha * (-1 * (Ylw[c] - Yiw[c]) * deriv_sigmoid(Yiw[c]))
print("biasIW : ", biasIW, '\n')

print("Forward Again:")
Ziw = np.dot(inp, weightIW) + biasIW  # Matrix Multiplication
Yiw = sigmoid(Ziw)
Zlw = np.dot(Yiw, weightLW) + biasLW
Ylw = sigmoid(Zlw)
E = 1/2 * sum((T-Ylw) ** 2)     # MSE - Hasil dari Y dibandingkan dengan T
print("Error / E : ", E,'\n')
```

it says "IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2" after iteration. Am i made a mistakes? Thank you for every responses.

Comment: The error is basically telling you that you that you are indexing an array beyond its size. Some of your arrays is shorter than you thought, or perhaps some of your loop iterates more elements than what is appropiate.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider pasting the full / relevant stack trace for errors for a file.

I ran your code through the debugger and found this error -

```py
line 73, in <module>
    delta = -1 * (Ylw[c] - Yiw[c]) * deriv_sigmoid(Yiw[c]) * inp[r]
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

```py
delta = -1 * (Ylw[c] - Yiw[c]) * deriv_sigmoid(Yiw[c]) * inp[r]
```

In this line `Ylw` is only of size 2, but your loop

```py
for c in range(4):
    for r in range(3):
        # turunan
        delta = -1 * (Ylw[c] - Yiw[c]) * deriv_sigmoid(Yiw[c]) * inp[r]
        # update weight
        weightIW[r][c] = weightIW[r][c] - alpha * delta
```

iterates `c` from 0 through 3, so it exceeds the length of `Ylw` hence the out of bounds error.